# What is the definitonal difference between the verb form of intrigue and interest?

Tags: meaning

Currently, they look exactly synonymous. I'd like to know their differences, no matter how small.

Intrigue:

> Arouse the curiosity or interest of; fascinate.

Interest:

> Excite the curiosity or attention of (someone).

Example sentence:

> That movie poster intrigued/interested me.

Comment: dictionary, dictionary, dictionary...

Comment: Can I interest you in a drink?  Can I intrigue you in a drink!!!!???? No they're not exactly synonymous. Also, if you're offering me a good well defined job with a good pay and benefits you'll interest me, if you're offering me a mysterious job but with a good pay, I'll be intrigued by your offer. (i.e ask for more information before commiting)

Comment: This question interests me, but that girl over there intrigues me.  Bye!

Comment: @P.O. That is because you are drawing on the 2nd definition of ‘interest’: ‘Persuade someone to undertake or acquire (something)’. I am wondering if they are exactly synonymous if I use the provided above definitions.

HotLicks, they seem interchangeable there.

Comment: A word may have different meanings and definition, it's only if ALL their definitions are exactly the same that you could say they are "exactly synonymous" overall. You could rephrase your question. As is, they're not, even in the narrow meaning you gave. In my mind, curiosity and some mystery is part of "intrigue", you cannot really be intrigued by something you know way in way out, like a movie you've seen a thousand times, you can still be interested by it though.